# Overload resolution ambiguity: String Builder kotlin?

Tags: android, string, kotlin, stringbuilder

I am using stringbuilder to concatenate strings

I get the error

```
Overload resolution ambiguity: 
public open fun append(p0: StringBuffer?): StringBuilder defined in java.lang.StringBuilder
public open fun append(p0: Any?): StringBuilder defined in java.lang.StringBuilder
public open fun append(p0: Boolean): StringBuilder defined in java.lang.StringBuilder
public open fun append(p0: Char): StringBuilder defined in java.lang.StringBuilder
public open fun append(p0: CharArray!): StringBuilder defined in java.lang.StringBuilder
public open fun append(p0: CharSequence?): StringBuilder defined in java.lang.StringBuilder
public open fun append(p0: Double): StringBuilder defined in java.lang.StringBuilder
public open fun append(p0: Float): StringBuilder defined in java.lang.StringBuilder
public open fun append(p0: Int): StringBuilder defined in java.lang.StringBuilder
public open fun append(p0: Long): StringBuilder defined in java.lang.StringBuilder
public open fun append(p0: String?): StringBuilder defined in java.lang.StringBuilder
```

This is my function

```
fun getCannotPurchaseItemMsg(domain: String?): String? {
    val builder = StringBuilder()
    if (localizationResult?.contentNotEnabledMessagePrefix != null)
        builder.append(localizationResult?.contentNotEnabledMessagePrefix)
    else if (genericMessages?.contentNotEnabledMessagePrefix != null)
        builder.append(genericMessages?.contentNotEnabledMessagePrefix)
    if (builder.toString().length == 0)
        return null
    builder.append(" ")
    //        builder.append(getAppCMSMain().getDomainName());
    builder.append(domain).append(" ")
    if (localizationResult?.contentNotEnabledMessageSuffix != null)
        builder.append(localizationResult?.contentNotEnabledMessageSuffix)
    else if (localizationResult?.contentNotEnabledMessageSuffix != null)
        builder.append(localizationResult?.contentNotEnabledMessageSuffix)
    return builder.toString()
}
```

This error is being said on

```
builder.append(localizationResult?.contentNotEnabledMessageSuffix)
```

The string is decalred as

```
var contentNotEnabledMessageSuffix: String? = null
```

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin seems to be too smart

Same object was being appended twice which caused the issue

```
if (localizationResult?.contentNotEnabledMessageSuffix != null)
        builder.append(localizationResult?.contentNotEnabledMessageSuffix)
    else if (genericMessages?.contentNotEnabledMessageSuffix != null)
        builder.append(genericMessages?.contentNotEnabledMessageSuffix)
```